# JavaFX How to 'hide' TitledPane back after expanding

Tags: javafx

I have TitledPane, which i want to hide back (after expanding - un-expand it) after pressing a button. Is there any way to do it? I didn't find any way :(  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
titledPane.setExpanded(false);
```

Complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TitledPaneExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Some content");
        Button button = new Button("OK");
        VBox content = new VBox(10, label, button);
        TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("Titled Pane", content);
        button.setOnAction(e -> titledPane.setExpanded(false));
        VBox root = new VBox(titledPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't close the titledPane. It just fixes it as it is - close or open.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't got it in the first time! Thank you very much for your time!